# Get Subscribers' Total Eligible Campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

What object from the [Retrieve marketing-cloud method](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/retrieve/) can be used to get the total number of campaigns which have been sent to each subscriber?

I'm finding it difficult to find the field I want within their documentation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no Object that represents this summary data exactly.

If you know the subscriber's `SubscriberKey` you can retrieve all of the SentEvent records.  Here's a sample SOAP envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:061c6bf2-8231-4eea-800b-8a558182d1bb</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-11-06T20:34:56.654Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-11-06T20:39:56.654Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-fddfc7b3-fc20-4415-b0c3-2759a545bf38-4">
            <o:Username>
               <!-- Removed-->
            </o:Username>
            <o:Password>
               <!-- Removed-->
            </o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
               <ClientID>
                  <!-- CLIENT MID GOES HERE-->
               </ClientID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>EventType</Properties>
            <Properties>BatchID</Properties>
            <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>ListID</Properties>
            <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>%@degdigital.com</Value>
            </Filter>
            <ContinueRequest />
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I have found the available data I need in the views which are accessible via Query Activities, but now I must figure out the process of executing Query and Extract Activities. Thanks!