# How to get data from Marketing Cloud standard data views using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I have a requirement where I have to get the data from Pre-defined data views eg: Send, Click etc. using REST API.

I am not able to find a solution for the same. Has anyone tried to do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST API is not able of fetching data from views, unfortunately. Generally, the data operations supported by REST are limited to upserts, and not reads - any use cases which require API to read data from SFMC require SOAP. This is explained in another question here on SFSE: [Bulk Retreive: Rest API - SF Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98652/bulk-retreive-rest-api-sf-marketing-cloud)

Using SOAP you will be able to access [Send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm), [Open](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/openevent.htm) and [Click](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/clickevent.htm) events, giving you tracking information you need.